# Log4j appending a particular classes Logging to a separate file.

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I need to configure log4j to output any logging for one particular class to a separate file.

Can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it can be done. Declare a logger for that class and give it a dedicated appender.

Comment: Adding to @SotiriosDelimanolis's comment - make sure the new logger is not `additive`.